# AWS SCP Tag Enforcer failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-organizations

I've got this Service Control Policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyEC2ActionsWithoutTags",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:CreateVpc”,
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*”,
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Name": [
                        "?*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I expect it to enforce a rule that tags are created with the `key` of `Name` and must have an associated `value` from a list I've defined in a separate policy otherwise resource creation should fail.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as security-groups still get created without a `key` `Name`.

The VPC and EC2 instance creation fails without a `Name` as expected, but not the security groups which I find odd.

Is there a way to enforce that all `ec2` taggable resources **must** have a `key` of `Name` and an associated value at creation time?

Comment: Docs write "To force users to specify tags when they create a resource, you must use the aws:RequestTag condition key or the aws:TagKeys condition key with the ForAnyValue modifier on the resource-creating action." You are not using `ForAnyValue` and/or `TagKeys`. Maybe this is reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try tag enforcement with SCPs, tag policies are fine, but SCPs to force tags is dangerous... we tried it and terraform and other services break the api workflow and ultimately stop your teams from being productive.

For example, if you set up an EMR cluster (which is backed by ec2) there is no tag pass-through via the EMR console over to the sub-assets in EC2 and the SCP they way you have it written above will break it.

We gave up on enforcing it using SCPs and are searching for a more robust solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mumbles. You're absolutely right and I found out the hard way. Wish I knew this earlier.
Did you ever find a more robust solution or is this something you're still on the lookout for one?